# https://name.onion vs. https://name.org differences

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onionaddress

What's the difference when I visit the same site in Tor Browser?

I call the `*.onion` URI or the `*.org` URI?

Is there any difference when both URI point to the same site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is an onion service, and the second is not. Onion services are only accessible from the Tor network and are routed differently from non-onion service websites. In general, onion services may be slightly slower, but can sometimes be more secure (if the website does not use TLS and HSTS).

> Is there any difference when both URI point to the same site?

How do you know they point to the same site? If the website operator officially advertises both addresses, then it's fine to use either address. But only use an address if you know that it's an official address run by the website operator. If it's not, one of them might be malicious and acting as a proxy, intercepting your traffic to the real site. Just because the webpages you see at both addresses look the same, doesn't mean they're actually the same. You should only access the website through its official address(es).